# How do I intrepret this graph?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

Recently as part of my project, I created a CNN for text-classification. I am getting higher test accuracy than training accuracy at a lower number of epochs, but eventually as it reaches the final epoch, training accuracy becomes equal to or slightly greater than test accuracy. Is getting higher initial test accuracy a problem? I am using 4646 data samples for training and 1162 data samples for testing.

[image]

Comment: Could be just random, have you tried running it again?

Comment: yeah, every time when i train the model i am getting higher test accuracy (even though not a big difference) initially at the first two epochs?Is it negligible?

Comment: Doesn't look like an issue to me. The differences are small anyway.

Comment: Okay.Thank you for answering